# reloading jsf/xhtml using dcevm in WebLogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic12c, dcevm, hotswapagent

I'm attempting to move away from JRebel to dcevm/hotswapagent (http://www.hotswapagent.org/) because of budget constraints.  My Java 1.7 app is built using ant and manually deployed to WebLogic 12.1.3 as an EAR file containing an EJB jar service layer and a WAR web layer.  My development is done using Eclipse.  I have hotswapagent working to the point where I can modify service layer EJBs or web layer classes eg. JSF beans), but the JSF views themselves are not refreshed when I make changes to the xhtml, save and reload.

I'll reiterate that I am not using Run As -> Run On Server from within Eclipse.  I am building the ear file and deploying it using the WebLogic console, and then modifying the code.  This approach worked well with JRebel.

I've tried specifying this property in ***hotswap-agent.properties***:

```
# Load static web resources from different directory.
#
# This setting is dependent on application server plugin(Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss, ...)
webappDir=/dev/workspace/myapp_web/WebContent/
```

... as well as these properties in ***web.xml***:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

... but without any luck.

Is this possible with hotswapagent and/or WebLogic 12.1?

Comment: Do you see the xhtml updated on the server (not in the browser, but in the 'deployed' application?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm not running from an exploded ear/war.  Do you mean in an internal temp/work WebLogic folder?